# Interactive SVG: Hover over one part, change the color of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to create an interactive SVG-Map.
I placed the Code from illustrator into a HTML and even managed to change the fill of some of my paths when you hover over them.
My problem is, that there is a white rectangle as well as text in front of my path: when I hover over those, nothing happens. I want to change that. My goal is to be able to hover over Text/ white Background/path and the path will always fill in my color (#ff7bac)

Here part of my SVG-Code:

```
    <a xlink:href="http://travelalberta.com" id="wohnrauemeLink">
    <g id="wohnraeume">
        <g id="wohnraeumeFill">
            <g>
                <path class="eckig" d="M1169,124.5v341.1h429V124.5H1169z M1390.5,445h-199.4l0-68.7h71v33.9h128.4V445z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <polygon id="wohnrauemeWhite" fill="#FFFFFF" points="1191.3,445.6 1191.2,372.3 1262.3,372.3 1262.2,410.1 1391,411.3 
            1390.5,445.7                "/>
        </g>
</a>
```

And my css:

```
path.eckig {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .6s fill;
      }

path.eckig:hover { 
    fill: #ff7bac;
    opacity: 1;
     }
```

I hope there is someone who can help me with this: I've been trying for days :I

******************** Edit *********************

Hey there :)
I'm still trying to figure this out so here is a simplified version:

https://jsfiddle.net/4tjzk8z5/11/

My goal is to be able to change the color of the red rectangle while I hover over the blue rectangle.

I tried to use JS this time, but it didn't work either:

```
function mouseoverblue(){
var myPara = document.getElementById("red");
myPara.style.color = "#123444";
```

}

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: you can do it with jQuery. What have you tried?

Comment: If you could create a minimal demo it would be useful but If the rectangle is **on top of the path** there isn't much you can do cross-browser wise. `pointer-events:none` is now supported in modern browsers and IE11+

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, that's exactly the case

Answer (score 2):

If you can put your svg code in the HTML page I suggest you to use CSS for make the animation.

[Here you can find a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs1wfs8r/)

CSS for your example:

```
/* Colors the polygon where you are hovering it or the path */
#wohnraeumeFill:hover+polygon,
polygon:hover{
    fill: #800;
}
```

---

EDIT

with CSS you can't select previous siblings, so you have to change the order of your SVG elements:

```
<svg>
    <g id="wohnraeume" transform="translate(-1100 -350)">

        <polygon id="wohnrauemeWhite" fill="#FFFFFF" points="1191.3,445.6 1191.2,372.3 1262.3,372.3 1262.2,410.1 1391,411.3 
            1390.5,445.7                "/>
        <g id="wohnraeumeFill">
            <g>
                <path class="eckig" d="M1169,124.5v341.1h429V124.5H1169z M1390.5,445h-199.4l0-68.7h71v33.9h128.4V445z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And the you can use the following CSS rule:

```
polygon:hover + #wohnraeumeFill path{
    fill: #800;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs1wfs8r/1/)

Comment: Thats better than my answer, +1

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) but: I don't want to change the color of the polygon, I want to change the color of the path while hovering over the polygon...

Answer (score 0):

If you used jQuery, it would be like this:

```
$('#svg1').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('#svg2').css('fill', 'red');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('#svg2').css('fill', 'blue');
    }
});
```

where `#svg1` and `#svg2` are `#wohnraeumeFill` and `#wohnrauemeWhite` respectively.

Comment: Sadly my SVG-Ids don't react to Javascript nor Jquery... Only CSS...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, sorry I just realised that an SVG will not accept `background-color`. I've edited my answer. Try using `fill` instead?

Comment: Can you put it in a JSFiddle please?

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help: https://jsfiddle.net/c1hbctc4/ 
It may be difficult because it's a rather big SVG-File

Answer (score 0):

Add mouse event functions `onmouseover` to set the color and `onmouseout` to reset it.

```
<rect id="blue" onmouseover="Img('#a02e3f')" onmouseout="Img('#123444')" x="753" y="375.3" fill="none" width="586.2" height="501.7"/>
```

Add the following in the script section : (And change the Load Type to `head`)

```
function Img(color){
    document.getElementById("red").style.fill=color;
}
```

PS: Or you can use JQuery, [Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4tjzk8z5)<.. And select `JQuery` in Frameworks and Extensions